# I am getting an exception when execute solr - Exception in building suggester index for: suggest

Tags: java, solr

```
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent  – Building suggester index for: suggest
org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester  – build()
ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – Exception in building suggester index for: suggest
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: need at least one suggestion
at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.FreeTextSuggester.build(FreeTextSuggester.java:338)
at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.FreeTextSuggester.build(FreeTextSuggester.java:278)
at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup.build(Lookup.java:165)
at org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester.build(SolrSuggester.java:142)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.buildSuggesterIndex(SuggestComponent.java:488)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent$SuggesterListener.newSearcher(SuggestComponent.java:472)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$6.call(SolrCore.java:1716)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to import data using SOLR component with solrconfig.xml, schema.xml and db-data-config.xml files and datasource configuration also perfect i think. While i am executing solr, showing above error.

Could you please help on this to resolve issue and let us know what was the issue....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have empty values in your suggest field.